# GUI MySQL database frontend

Tags: php, mysql, database, user-interface, web-applications

I have a slightly hopeless wish list for a piece of software, and I don't know if it exists.

*What it needs:*

- To be free to use (in a small business)
- To run on a php server with a MySql database
- To be a GUI database front end
- To do more that CRUD. In particular I need to be able to create custom forms, and insert and delete multiple records from multiple tables in one action. This sort of process building is the main criteria I am looking for.
- To have some ajax support so it looks good
- To deal with all the logins automatically
- To not require any proper programming. The whole project can be built in the browser
- Hopefully have some advanced features like sending email, scheduled jobs, etc.
- The end product has to be client-facing, so it can't be an administrator tool where someone who doesn't know what they are doing can break it
- To make you a cup of coffee if you want one.

Can you tell me if it does exist?

Comment: PS: I don't mean to abuse your hospitality with a dull question like this, but I so impressed by the quality of other answers that I hope you can help with mine

Comment: Tagging this because I don't think it exists but if it does I will make many clients very happy.

Comment: Take a look at [Drupal](http://drupal.org/).

Comment: Why don't you try SQLyog. But its free. The free version is available here: https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list. This has basic functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Well I highly doubt you are going to find any solution that does ALL of what you are asking, especially if you want it all to be free. But I will point you to [phpMyAdmin](http://phpmyadmin.net).

If you haven't come across it yet, it is a web-based front end for a MySQL database (runs on a php server). It is easy to deploy and can maintain multiple user logins. It's not too strong in the ajax department and I've never heard of anything like scheduled jobs or email for it but that stuff can all be done in different ways.

Think of phpMyAdmin as a database editor on the web, it's not going to be something you're going to want to hand over to clients to mess around with though.

Comment: It's an industry staple. At the very least try it. I've been using it for ~8 years, and never needed anything else.

Comment: I make all of my tables in phpmyadmin. It's great.

Comment: Thank-you for this suggestion. Actually I should have specified that the end product has to be client-facing, so myAdmin wouldn't work I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

To the OP, this meets almost all of your requirements, including Ajax, Client facing, web based build, no proper coding required, etc... except it does not make coffee, and is not free, but at only $48 one-time, it's not a deal breaker:

PHP MYSQL Form Maker
http://mysqlreports.com/

Answer (score 2):

There's a newer tool that fits a lot of your needs. You can check it out here:

[Eliacom Enhanced SQL Portal (ESP)](http://www.eliacom.com/)

There is also a demo that you can use to login to any database server here (note that to use it, it will install a few extra tables into your database to hold formatting information that you set in the front end):

[Eliacom ESP Demo](http://www.eliacom.com/esp/)

Here's how it breaks down with your criteria:

- **It's free**
- **It's written in PHP** To run on a php server with a
  MySql database
- **It is a GUI** It's basically as easy to use as Excel for inline editing. Organize your tables in trees, layout and rename columns, all from the GUI.
- **It does more that CRUD** This probably its strongest point. You can create pretty much anything. For really fancy stuff you need to know a little HTML. You can definitely delete multiple records very easily. Inserting multiple records can be done via a past function (or upload).
- **It's completely ajax and it looks pretty modern**
- **It deals with logging in and session handling (it locks sessions after a while too)** With a single instance you can log into any server (that you have access to of course).
- **You don't need any programming.** If you want to make very snappy forms, you need to know some HTML (the forms look pretty good even without that).
- **It's completely web-based and controlled via a browser**
- **The base system doesn't have scheduling/email, but you can purchase an add-on that has scheduling of jobs/emailing, etc.** I believe they already have this if they are hosting it for you. Just not in the general release. In the general release, if you know a little PHP, you can add listeners to when tables are modified and do things like send emails (you add these from the front end).
- **The base product is meant for database administration, but there are add-ons for purchase.** They have an app for purchase that gives you the ability to give control to other users (with a lot of permission settings of what they can/can't do so they can't break stuff). They also have a Publisher app that you can create a link that will allow forms/tables to be published to the open internet (for public data viewing/entering).
- **Coffee...** They take requests from users, so if you have a feature request, you can contact them.

Comment: Links do not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, although the products went EOL December 18, 2009, the last versions of MySQL Query Browser and MySQL Administrator are still available for download totally for free.

Hey, I still use them today.

It only fulfills a few needs

- To be free to use (in a small business)
- To be a GUI database front end
- To deal with all the logins automatically (sort of)

[**Click here and get it while Oracle isn't looking ... QUICK !!!**](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-gui-tools-noinstall-5.0-r17-win32.zip/from/http://mirror.trouble-free.net/mysql_mirror/)

Answer (score 0):

What about [**MySQL Workbench**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/index.html)? It is provided under **GPL** License

> MySQL Workbench provides DBAs and developers an integrated tools
>   environment for:
>
> - Database Design & Modeling
> - SQL Development
> - Database Administration
> - Database Migration

[image: screen0]

It  is directly available for Windows, Linux(Ubuntu, Rad Hat Enterprise, Fedora) & OS X from [Download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) page! (Source Code also).

Answer (score 0):

Would VFront worth a mention? I haven't used it myself but was looking for similar solutions:

http://www.vfront.org/

Here's an excerpt from its website:

- VFront is useful for companies,brands or organizations, which use MySQL or PostgreSQL, in need of an easy consulting or modyfing access to database by their own employed whithout developing a specific client for that but simply using a web browser.
- Think about VFront as an interface tool for database, similar for some functions to MS access, but taking the lead with an easy access via web.VFront is not a database administration tool like phpMyAdmin and it's not replacing it : interface is for basic user working on data.
- VFront is created for non-expert users capable to work safely on data using an intuitive graphic interface.
- VFront is particularly useful when various and/or several users have to access to database using different privileges: a highly customizable system of groups and privileges makes access possible for various employed to specific tables or views, shows/hides specific fields, sets rules for input validation and keeps under control all the database activities.
- VFront has export data modules, statistics and report management based on xml, xsl and xsl-fo protocols.
- VFront can be useful too for those who, generically, are in need of an easy to install and configure database front-end.