# More than CRUD frontend for MySQL not Access

Tags: mysql, forms, frontend, subforms

(in fact MariaDB - fork of MySQL)

More than CRUD: It's got to be able to do things like forms and subforms, i.e. be "client-facing".  Rules out phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, sqlYog, etc.

I've seen this:
[GUI MySQL database frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842618/gui-mysql-database-frontend): no solution then, but this was 2 1/2 years ago.

I've also found the LibreOffice Base idea... but of course this doesn't use an Apache or other server.  I've tried this route and found that these forms didn't work very satisfactorily: buttons and textboxes lack the configurability of JQuery equivalents, for example.

The plan is to find a solution in Window$ which can then be used in Linux.  So not Kexi.

So I've reluctantly started rolling my own: PHP and Javascript, using things like JQuery Select2 for Combo boxes.  It'll work, eventually, but because so many people must be looking for this sort of thing, I find it hard to believe there isn't a low/no-cost project which does this: i.e. generates forms-subforms, Access style, using PHP and Javascript, where the Javascript and PHP can then be tweaked.

Might Drupal be a possible answer? My impression is that this would mean much to learn before bearing any fruit.

Comment: This question belongs to [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DanFromGermany thanks... I'll put it there no problem, I'm just wondering whether anyone who might know the answer looks at that particular forum?

Comment: @DanFromGermany SR mod here. Please make sure to add a link to our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/46) - we require much more information than an average question here contains. Thanks!